# Datatable shows empty data in row

Tags: jquery, datatable

I have a data-table which has two  rows.The first row is comign directly fro the db and is rendered on UI. The second row is added via addRow method in javascript.  Please see the code below :

Here's the table row in html source:

[image]

And here's the code to access the row:

```
 var table = "";

 table = $("#orders").DataTable({
                ajax: {
                    url: "/api/dfddsfs?id="+ id,
                    dataSrc: ""
                },
                columns: [
                    {

                        data: "product.description",
                    },
                    {

                        data: "quantity"
                    },
                    {

                        data: "product.productPrice"
                    },
                    {
                        data: "discount"
                    },
                    {
                        data: "product.isTaxable"
                    },
                    {
                        data: "finalPrice"
                    },
                    {
                        data: "lineItemTotal"
                    },
                    {
                        data: "product.description",
                        render: function (data, type, product) {

                            return "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash js-delete' data-lineitem-id=" + data + "></span>";


                        }
                    }
                ]
            });


 $('#addRow').click(function () {
    if ($("[name='Product.description']").valid()) {
        //Create a row if not null
        var rowHtml = $("#newRow").find("tr")[0].outerHTML;
        //Add row to the table
        $('#orders').DataTable().row.add($(rowHtml)).draw();
        //Set the first column to product description
        $('#orders tr:first-child td:first-child').first().html($("#product").val());
        //Set second column to quantity
        $('#orders tr:first-child td:nth-child(2)').append("2");

        //Set third column to price
        $('#orders tr:first-child td:nth-child(3)').first().html("123");
       //Set fourth column to dicount
        $('#orders tr:first-child td:nth-child(4)').append("10");
        //Set fifth column as a checkbox
        $('#orders tr:first-child td:nth-child(5)').append("<label><input type='checkbox' value=''></label>");
        //clear the product input text
        $('#product').val('');
    }
    else
        alert("Please choose a product");
});




     $('#save').click(function (evt) {

           table.rows().every(function (rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop) {
                   var data = this.data();
                   console.log("data is " + JSON.stringify(data));
            });

      });
```

Here's the console result:

```
data is <br/>
data is {"product":{"description":"","productPrice":"","isTaxable":""},"quantity":"","discount":"","finalPrice":"","lineItemTotal":""}
8:352 data is {"delete":"<i class='fa fa-pencil-square' aria-hidden='true'></i> <i class='fa fa-minus-square .js-delete' aria-hidden='true'></i>","id":21,"quantity":12,"discount":12,"product":{"id":501,"upc":null,"description":"Eggs","restockQty":26,"productPrice":40000,"isTaxable":false,"productCost":11000,"image":"","productCode":"01 B 04","packing":20,"productWholesalePrice":20000},"productId":501,"salesOrder":null,"salesOrderId":8,"lineTaxes":9,"isTaxable":true,"lineItemTotal":999,"finalPrice":9999}
```

As you can see, the result shows to data objects. One with values and one without values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `.DataTable()` again inside save button click. You must have initialised datatable outside the button click, store it in a variable and use same for iterating over rows

```
var table = $('#orders').DataTable();// store previously initialised datatable in variable

$('#save').click(function (evt) {
      //var table = $('#orders').DataTable(); -- remove it
       table.rows().every(function (rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop) {
               var data = this.data();
               console.log("data is " + JSON.stringify(data));
        });

  });
```

Comment: Followed your suggestion but still getting empty values. Please see my edits.

Comment: This should work but need to check if there are any other errors on browser. Can you recreate your issue on code snippet or on JSFiddle so that i can take a look at it

Comment: `var table = $('#orders').DataTable()` is correct if you not have the table instance on hand.

Comment: Please check my edited question. I was able to view the data coning directly from db but not the one I added manually. I can actually see both rows in the html but I cant access the value of the manually added row.

Comment: Datatable accepting data in json and rendering it on UI, it is using same json internally when you iterate rows but it will not find data in JSON which you have added manually and that is the reason `table.rows.every` not working for you. Instead of using datable API, you can create your own code to read table rows and put in json or plain text.

Comment: So do you mean to say that If I add a row manually then it will be visible in DOM but will not be accessible via datatable api?

Comment: @bangbang yes, if you add row manually, it will display in DOM, but not be accessible via datatable. Also in pagination you only see "show 1 to 1 of 1 entries" at bottom. am i correct ?

Comment: I actually see "1 of 2", however, if I search for this manually added item, I don't see it.